# CSS Display Elements on Hover

Tags: html, css

I have the following code. Whenever I hover on "Third Level", it disappears.
In other words: I want to show first-level, second-level, and third-level when the user hovers on the third-level.

```css
.level2 {
  display: none;
}
.level3 {
  display: none;
}
    
.level1:hover + .level2 {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

.level2:hover + .level3 {
  display: block;
  color: blue;
}

.level2:hover {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Display Elements on Hover</h2>

<div class="level1">1. First Level</div>
<div class="level2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1.1. Second Level</div>
<div class="level3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1.1.1 Third Level.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you move off of the level 2 element onto the level 3 element, there is no active style telling it to display anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest the elements. This will work:

```css
.level2 {
  display: none;
}

.level3 {
  display: none;
}

.level1:hover .level2 {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

.level2:hover .level3 {
  display: block;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h2>Display Elements on Hover</h2>

<div class="level1">1. First Level
  <div class="level2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1.1. Second Level
    <div class="level3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1.1.1 Third Level.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I checked your code and it is working fine.
But is there any way to fix it without nesting?

Comment: I don't think. If was helpful please accept my answer :)